# how to generate SHA256 with 32 bytes for a given string?

Tags: javascript, sha256

I am looking for javascript code for generating a SHA256 with **32 bytes** for a given string

this code is suppose to work inside a browser so it should work without any dependencies

so far I found the following function that gives 64 bytes SHA256:

```
/**
* Secure Hash Algorithm (SHA256)
* http://www.webtoolkit.info/
* Original code by Angel Marin, Paul Johnston
**/

function SHA256(s){
 var chrsz = 8;
 var hexcase = 0;

 function safe_add (x, y) {
 var lsw = (x & 0xFFFF) + (y & 0xFFFF);
 var msw = (x >> 16) + (y >> 16) + (lsw >> 16);
 return (msw << 16) | (lsw & 0xFFFF);
 }

 function S (X, n) { return ( X >>> n ) | (X << (32 - n)); }
 function R (X, n) { return ( X >>> n ); }
 function Ch(x, y, z) { return ((x & y) ^ ((~x) & z)); }
 function Maj(x, y, z) { return ((x & y) ^ (x & z) ^ (y & z)); }
 function Sigma0256(x) { return (S(x, 2) ^ S(x, 13) ^ S(x, 22)); }
 function Sigma1256(x) { return (S(x, 6) ^ S(x, 11) ^ S(x, 25)); }
 function Gamma0256(x) { return (S(x, 7) ^ S(x, 18) ^ R(x, 3)); }
 function Gamma1256(x) { return (S(x, 17) ^ S(x, 19) ^ R(x, 10)); }

 function core_sha256 (m, l) {
 var K = new Array(0x428A2F98, 0x71374491, 0xB5C0FBCF, 0xE9B5DBA5, 0x3956C25B, 0x59F111F1, 0x923F82A4, 0xAB1C5ED5, 0xD807AA98, 0x12835B01, 0x243185BE, 0x550C7DC3, 0x72BE5D74, 0x80DEB1FE, 0x9BDC06A7, 0xC19BF174, 0xE49B69C1, 0xEFBE4786, 0xFC19DC6, 0x240CA1CC, 0x2DE92C6F, 0x4A7484AA, 0x5CB0A9DC, 0x76F988DA, 0x983E5152, 0xA831C66D, 0xB00327C8, 0xBF597FC7, 0xC6E00BF3, 0xD5A79147, 0x6CA6351, 0x14292967, 0x27B70A85, 0x2E1B2138, 0x4D2C6DFC, 0x53380D13, 0x650A7354, 0x766A0ABB, 0x81C2C92E, 0x92722C85, 0xA2BFE8A1, 0xA81A664B, 0xC24B8B70, 0xC76C51A3, 0xD192E819, 0xD6990624, 0xF40E3585, 0x106AA070, 0x19A4C116, 0x1E376C08, 0x2748774C, 0x34B0BCB5, 0x391C0CB3, 0x4ED8AA4A, 0x5B9CCA4F, 0x682E6FF3, 0x748F82EE, 0x78A5636F, 0x84C87814, 0x8CC70208, 0x90BEFFFA, 0xA4506CEB, 0xBEF9A3F7, 0xC67178F2);
 var HASH = new Array(0x6A09E667, 0xBB67AE85, 0x3C6EF372, 0xA54FF53A, 0x510E527F, 0x9B05688C, 0x1F83D9AB, 0x5BE0CD19);
 var W = new Array(64);
 var a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j;
 var T1, T2;

 m[l >> 5] |= 0x80 << (24 - l % 32);
 m[((l + 64 >> 9) << 4) + 15] = l;

 for ( var i = 0; i<m.length; i+=16 ) {
 a = HASH[0];
 b = HASH[1];
 c = HASH[2];
 d = HASH[3];
 e = HASH[4];
 f = HASH[5];
 g = HASH[6];
 h = HASH[7];

 for ( var j = 0; j<64; j++) {
 if (j < 16) W[j] = m[j + i];
 else W[j] = safe_add(safe_add(safe_add(Gamma1256(W[j - 2]), W[j - 7]), Gamma0256(W[j - 15])), W[j - 16]);

 T1 = safe_add(safe_add(safe_add(safe_add(h, Sigma1256(e)), Ch(e, f, g)), K[j]), W[j]);
 T2 = safe_add(Sigma0256(a), Maj(a, b, c));

 h = g;
 g = f;
 f = e;
 e = safe_add(d, T1);
 d = c;
 c = b;
 b = a;
 a = safe_add(T1, T2);
 }

 HASH[0] = safe_add(a, HASH[0]);
 HASH[1] = safe_add(b, HASH[1]);
 HASH[2] = safe_add(c, HASH[2]);
 HASH[3] = safe_add(d, HASH[3]);
 HASH[4] = safe_add(e, HASH[4]);
 HASH[5] = safe_add(f, HASH[5]);
 HASH[6] = safe_add(g, HASH[6]);
 HASH[7] = safe_add(h, HASH[7]);
 }
 return HASH;
 }

 function str2binb (str) {
 var bin = Array();
 var mask = (1 << chrsz) - 1;
 for(var i = 0; i < str.length * chrsz; i += chrsz) {
 bin[i>>5] |= (str.charCodeAt(i / chrsz) & mask) << (24 - i % 32);
 }
 return bin;
 }

 function Utf8Encode(string) {
 string = string.replace(/\r\n/g,'\n');
 var utftext = '';

 for (var n = 0; n < string.length; n++) {

 var c = string.charCodeAt(n);

 if (c < 128) {
 utftext += String.fromCharCode(c);
 }
 else if((c > 127) && (c < 2048)) {
 utftext += String.fromCharCode((c >> 6) | 192);
 utftext += String.fromCharCode((c & 63) | 128);
 }
 else {
 utftext += String.fromCharCode((c >> 12) | 224);
 utftext += String.fromCharCode(((c >> 6) & 63) | 128);
 utftext += String.fromCharCode((c & 63) | 128);
 }

 }

 return utftext;
 }

 function binb2hex (binarray) {
 var hex_tab = hexcase ? '0123456789ABCDEF' : '0123456789abcdef';
 var str = '';
 for(var i = 0; i < binarray.length * 4; i++) {
 str += hex_tab.charAt((binarray[i>>2] >> ((3 - i % 4)*8+4)) & 0xF) +
 hex_tab.charAt((binarray[i>>2] >> ((3 - i % 4)*8 )) & 0xF);
 }
 return str;
 }

 s = Utf8Encode(s);
 return binb2hex(core_sha256(str2binb(s), s.length * chrsz));
}
```

Comment: This code does not return 64 bytes, but 32 only. But as these 32 bytes are encoded in hex, you need 64 chars to encode 32 bytes of data, ie two characters (`00` to `FF`) for each byte.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The result you're receiving actually **are** 32 bytes.

Let's have a look at an example:

```
console.log(SHA256("test"));
```

returns:

```
9f86d081884c7d659a2feaa0c55ad015a3bf4f1b2b0b822cd15d6c15b0f00a08
```

What we see is a string representation of 32 bytes which results in 64 bytes of individual chars. However a group of two chars is actually one byte, ranging from 0 up to 255 in decimal.

> 9f (hex) -> 10011111 (binary) -> 159 (decimal)
>
> 86 (hex) -> 10000110 (binary) -> 134 (decimal)

and so on.

If you want to store the 64 character sequence as 'real' 32 bytes, you need to convert pairs of two characters to an 8-bit unsigned integer value (0-255) and put those in a JavaScript typed array.

For example ...

```js
let hexString = "9f86d081884c7d659a2feaa0c55ad015a3bf4f1b2b0b822cd15d6c15b0f00a08";
let unsignedIntegers = hexString.match(/[\dA-F]{2}/gi).map(function(s) {
  return parseInt(s, 16);
});
let typedArray = new Uint8Array(unsignedIntegers);
console.log(typedArray);
```

... gives a 32 bytes Uint8Array.